# Use of semicolon - in this sentence - as a way to add additional information

Tags: word-usage, semicolons

I am trying to list the things that one should keep in mind when traveling with kids, but I also want to convey that child should not be allowed to travel with a teen alone. Am I using the semicolon correctly?

I read in a guide that **Semicolons separate clauses or phrases that are related and that receive equal emphasis**

1. Semicolons join two independent clauses (complete sentences) that
   are closely related if no coordinating conjunction is used.
2. Semicolons signal to a reader that the information in both sentences
   should be taken together.

My sentence:

Planning a trip with a toddler? Your 'travel-essentials' checklist should include the following things; however, note that you need to be 21 or above to drive alone with the toddler:

toddler seat, diapers, and baby feed

Comment: No. You need a full colon there. Plus, you can't have the colon at the end to continue on because toddler seat, diapers, and baby feed are not things to "keep in mind," they are to keep handy rather.

Comment: @Kris I have made the changes. I always thought that we can use a semicolon to add extra information. I think I was wrong :)

Comment: "Your 'travel-essentials' checklist should include various essentials mentioned below; however, note that you need to be 21 or above to drive alone with the toddler." is correctly punctuated but I'd say not in the spirit of your 'rule 2'. I'd use: "Planning a trip with a toddler? (You need firstly to be aware that **you need to be 21 or above to drive alone with the toddler**!)  Your 'travel-essentials' checklist should include the following things: toddler seat, diapers, and baby feed." // With an example where one sentence (other than the  "Planning a trip with a toddler?" intro) ...

Comment: might seem more appropriate, the use of semicolon and colon in a single sentence is almost always considered very poor style. I'd put this in an answer, but the main points have been covered before.